# Automation of Cygwin configuration with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cygwin

I have installed Cygwin using PowerShell scripting.

I am doing the following step manually:

1. Running a new cygwin bash shell (after the edit of `cygwin.bat`) and enter:

   ```
   mount --change-cygdrive-prefix /
   chmod +r /etc/passwd /etc/group
   chmod 755 /var
   ```
2. Start Cygwin bash shell and run `ssh-host-config`. Answer yes to all the key generation questions.

Is it possible to automate these things in PowerShell scripts, like installing Cygwin, then doing steps 1 and 2 in a single shot?

Comment: If you `cd` into the cygwin directory you can just run `bash.exe ssh-host-config --yes`
Don't see why you couldn't just add that to the bottom of step 1 to do it all in 1 step

Comment: If I run "bash.exe ssh-host-config --yes " , I am getting an error "the term bash.exe is not recognized as a cmdlet" , and one more thing is that I have to Cygwin.bat file not bash.exe file

Comment: You need to `cd` into `%cygwinhome%\bin` where all the executable files are, one being `bash.exe`. You can just append the above command into your cygwin.bat file to generate the keys automatically

Comment: Thank you very much , one last clarification , after running the "run ssh-host-config" , there is a step to "Enter the value of CYGWIN for the daemon" , how to perform this step silently with a value without the intervention of user input during exeution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this command:

```
bash.exe ssh-host-config --yes -u "Cygwinuser" -c "binmode ntsec tty" -w "pwd@123"
cygrunsrv -S sshd
```

Later go to services.msc to check if the service is running or not